# Android On Click of notification open activity based on condition

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have two activities, A(Login) and B(DashBoard), i create notification for specific times and if the user is already in activity B, then on clicking on the notification nothing should happen and if Application is closed or not opened, on clicking on notification Activity A needs to be opened. how can this be achieved.TIA

i tried the following in braodcastreceiver

```
   @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("NotificationReceiver","NotificationReceiver");
    if(ActivityB.instance!=null){

    }else{
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.test","com.test.ActivityA");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

But when my application not opened or closed, else is not executing.

Comment: Can you post your code here. Whatever you have tried?

Comment: Maintain flag in `SharedPreferences` as per user login and on notification click check this flag and make your decision

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of activities in your application class using activityLifeCycleCallbacks

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements my.package.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); 
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);          
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Stopped", activity.getLocalClassName());

}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Started", activity.getLocalClassName());

}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity SaveInstanceState", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Paused", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Destroyed", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Created", activity.getLocalClassName());
}
}
```

Next receive onClick of the notification in a broadcast, check if activityB is opened from your application class and make a decision